# How can I redirect "everything" to https://www.example.com?

Tags: apache-httpd

How can I redirect "everything" to https://www.example.com?

Attention: without using rewrites, without using htaccess; only using redirects, because is the correct way, as stated in the Apache manual (I have root access to the server).

And "everything" means the other 3 alternatives: http://example.com, http://www.example.com, https://example.com

Comment: Well, adding this line to 000-default.conf: "Redirect permanent / https_//www.example.com/", I can redirect http_//example.com and https_//example.com. But, I can't figure out how to redirect https_//example.com to https_//www.example.com – user68563 1 min ago   edit

Comment: CORRECTION: Well, adding this line to 000-default.conf: "Redirect permanent / https_//www.example.com/", I can redirect http_//example.com and http_//www_example.com. But, I can't figure out how to redirect https_//example.com to https_//www.example.com

Comment: I had to give up and go partially with mod rewrite and got it working like this: **000-default.conf** added `Redirect permanent / https://www.example.com/` + **default-ssl.conf** added: `RewriteEngine On + RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR] + RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=www.example.com [NC] + RewriteRule ^(.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [NS,L,R=permanent]`

Answer (score 1):

```
# Force SSL via 301 Redirect...
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: If you can't do this in .htaccess or .conf, you can do it in code. Just do the redirect the same, if it's port 80, 301 redirect to https : //HOST.

Comment: Please read my second anwser above which starts with "correction"

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

`<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com
    Redirect permanent / https://www.example.com/
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.com
    Redirect permanent / https://www.example.com/
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.example.com
    ...
    <configs>
    ...
</VirtualHost>`

Comment: I've tried that but it did't work. I'm not using virtual hosts, but instead 000-default.conf e default-ssl.conf. Maybe, I've adapted wrong. Here's how I've done it in default-ssl.conf: ServerAlias example.com
Redirect permanent / https://www.example.com/
ServerName www.example.com
DocumentRoot /var/www