# Redirection of https://example.com to https://www.example.com not working

Tags: apache-httpd, ssl, webserver

I am running WordPress on Ubuntu. I am have used let's encrypt SSL.
I want to redirect everything to `https://www.lifesmile.ae`. But it does not work as you can check yourself.

I have the following redirection on my WordPress `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.lifesmile.ae/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.lifesmile.ae/$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

I have tried editing `000-default.conf` file and `default-ssl.conf` file but of no success.

As mention in some blog, I also tried to use `Redirect permanent / https_//www.lifesmile.ae/` but it does not work. Can you please help me to solve this ??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I redirect "everything" to https://www.example.com?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/303315/how-can-i-redirect-everything-to-https-www-example-com)

Comment: I tried all the step and probably like everything mentioned in this site but still of no success

Comment: IN that case please include your full virtual host definitions in your question